# no result on exact match in specific field

Tags: solr

A really weired behaviour on my solr server:

Normally there are 4 documents matching my query while searching for "Erdnägel".
3 documents carry that exact word on the field "description" and 1 document does "Erdnägel" have in the field "title".

But solr only returns the 3 named documents with searchterm "Erdnägel". I only get all of those four docs, if searchterm is "Erdnäge".

Schema for the title-field:

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory" dictionary="vkf_de_DE.dic" affix="vkf_de_DE.aff" ignoreCase="true" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

...

<field name="oxtitle" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="oxtitle_raw" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Everything seems to be okay, because using the analysis-tool on the field "oxtitle" using "Erdnägel" as term, I get that exact word from the index.

I also tested a direct query on solr-admin->query:

using "oxtitle:'Erdnägel'" -> 0 results

using "oxtitle_raw:'Erdnägel'" 1 result

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Could you add the appropriate analaysis information for the `oxtitle` field, with Erdnägel as both the indexed and queried value? I'm guessing since you have HunspellSteamFilterFactory only defined when querying, you're left with a different token than when indexing (or that the word delimiter assumes ä as a separator).

Comment: omg .... that was the issue! I really missed the exact query result. In fact, the Hunspell-Stemmer made "Erdnagel" from "Erdnägel". You ´re right. In that case "Erdnagel" isn´t in the index. Hm, seems to be a typical failure. The more you watch a text, the less you recognize the differences ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the HunspellStemFilterFactory defined only for querying, you're probably left with a different token in the index than the token used for querying.

You can see this if you go to the analysis page, enter Erdnägel for both the index and query values, and see if the result contains the same token on both sides.